# Is there a gcc option to print the target triplet when cross-compiling?

Tags: gcc, clang, cross-compiling, compiler-options

`gcc -dumpmachine` is almost perfect, but it doesn't respect flags that affect the target.  On the other hand, `clang` does:

```
$ gcc -dumpmachine
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
$ gcc -dumpmachine -m32
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

```
$ clang -dumpmachine
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
$ clang -dumpmachine -m32
i386-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Probably not, as far as the GCC compiler itself is concerned `-m32` doesn't change the target, just like how `-march=i486` doesn't change the target to `i486-unknown-linux-gnu`.

Comment: I think the answer's no. The clang behaviour looks useful though (especially if the `-m32` result honours the `-march` option too, e.g. prints `i686-...` if appropriate)

Comment: N.B. `-m32` is not "cross-compiling", it's just using a different instruction set of the same architecture, it's referred to as a multilib target.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Actually I thought `clang` would do that but it doesn't; even though `-march-armv7-a` will cause its target to change from `armv5te-...` to `arm7-...`, `-dumpmachine` output stays the same.  Lame!

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps `-print-multiarch` is useful. According to the documentations, this option "display the target's normalized GNU triplet, used as a component in the library path".

In my box (x86_64) I get:

```
$ gcc -print-multiarch
x86_64-linux-gnu
$ gcc -print-multiarch -m32
i386-linux-gnu
```

Comment: That would be perfect except all it prints on my computer is a single newline :/

Comment: Oops, pity. I learned about the option here: https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/Tuples . Apparently it was integrated upstream in gcc 4.7.